# swift tableview load image by using SDWebImage 4.3.0

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, reusability, sdwebimage

i would like to use SDWebImage to load tableview image stably, but it doesn't work, it keep start the previous image of the reuse cell before loading the correct images.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell


        let myStorage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let tempImage = myStorage.child("CompanyImage/\(companyList[indexPath.row].photoNameInStorage).jpg")

        tempImage.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle any errors
                self.createAlert(title: "error", message: "")
            } else {
                cell.companyImage.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: nil, options: [.cacheMemoryOnly, .highPriority])
            }
        }

        cell.companyName.text = self.companyList[indexPath.row].name
        cell.address.text = self.companyList[indexPath.row].address
        cell.startDate.text = self.companyList[indexPath.row].startDate
        cell.endDate.text = self.companyList[indexPath.row].endDate
        cell.conditions.text = self.companyList[indexPath.row].conditions

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove old image before loading new image, put below line above your code:

```
tempImage.image = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use this method to set your Image in cell:

   `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       <#code#>
   }`
2. And make sure you have the correctly Cell with a:

   `if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
   /* set your image */
   } else {
   /* set a default image like a white or transparent one */
   }`

Comment: i update the code to show you what i wrote in the func cellForRowAt, can you let me know what to write inside the func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)